# Is it possible to have multiple subtype fields in a Feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, domains, subtype

I am creating a feature class which will be used for data capture via a Geoform template in AGOL.  This has 17 fields.

I have set field 1 as a subtype with 3 options (3 types of conservation zones).
Field 2 contains the name of the conservation zones and I have set this up as 3 domains - one for each available option in field 1, each domain has around 30 different values.

I then also need field 5 to have its own set of subtypes (8 options) all of which will be linked to individual domains in field 6 (each domain holding around 30 different options)

Is this possible?

From the help pages on the ESRI website it appears that I am only able to assign one field to have subtypes, and any other "drop down menus" in the feature class  must be domains.  This means that everything is dictated by the subtype chosen in field 1.

The 2 fields I need as subtypes are completely independent of each other.

Does anybody know of a workaround for what I am trying to do?
Is there a better app than Geoforms in AGOL that will let me achieve what I am trying to do?

I am Using ArcMap 10.2.2 with an advanced licence and have an organisational AGOL account.

Comment: As Midavalo has stated below, this is not possible in a feature class, however, instead of using a Geofrom I have been able to achieve this using Survey 123, which allows you to link multiple fields together in the same way that subtypes and Domains work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **no** you cannot have multiple subtype fields on a single feature class.  You are only able to select one field as the subtype field in the Feature Class properties.

There are some suggestions on the ArcGIS Ideas site asking for subtypes to be made available on multiple field, like this one - [Allow subtypes on multiple fields](https://community.esri.com/ideas/2826)